# Record audio (FLAC or WAV) in ReactJs and use Speech2Text from google using ruby backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, audio, google-cloud-speech

I need to record an audio through front-end. I'm using [React Mic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mic) and [mic-recorder-to-mp3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mic-recorder-to-mp3) ReactJS libraries. Everything is fine, I'm managing to download the blob of the audio and hear it. Although, I need to upload it to my back-end so I can use [Google SpeechToText API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/?&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=latam-BR-all-pt-dr-skws-all-all-trial-b-dr-1007178-LUAC0009046&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_331159561915-ADGP_SKWS%20%7C%20Multi%20~%20Developers%20%7C%20Speech-Recognition-KWID_43700042824516611-kwd-475503111819-userloc_1001541&utm_term=KW_%2Bspeech%20%2Btext-ST_%2BSpeech%20%2BText&gclid=CjwKCAiAzanuBRAZEiwA5yf4ukocIEdZ3hAym3CJLfbpCgZqqS3RCSbKIcZnAFoxQzEEw56EshHHexoCZoMQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) to extract text from audio.

That is the script that im using but its not returning any result, i think that is cos' the audio recorded dont have the right encodings.

```
require "google/cloud/speech"
require 'json'


# Instantiates a client
speech = Google::Cloud::Speech.new

# The name of the audio file to transcribe
file_name = "./newmp3.mp3"


# The raw audio
audio_file = File.binread file_name
encoding = :LINEAR16
# The audio file's encoding and sample rate        
    config =  {
                encoding: "LINEAR16",
                language_code: "pt-BR",
                model: "default",
                sample_rate_hertz: 16000
            }

    audio  = { content: audio_file }

# Detects speech in the audio file
response = speech.recognize(config, audio)

results = response.results

puts response
```

Comment: LINEAR16 is PCM encoded audio data, but you are sending an mp3 file. You need to convert the mp3 file to PCM first.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an mp3 file to the API, but you are telling it that the file is encoded as LINEAR16 (PCM data). This will not work.

According to the [speech API docs](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding#audio-encodings), MP3 is only supported through the beta API.

One easy way to resolve this is to use a simple external audio encoder like ffmpeg, and convert it to something like FLAC before sending it over:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 output.flac
```

Then set `FLAC` as the audio type for your `encoding` setting. But remember you cannot upload more then 1 minute of audio using this method. Uploading longer files has to be done asynchronously by using Google Cloud servers for storage.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this in my frontend using this library [1] but if not works i'll try in backend with this other gem [2] 

[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg
[2]: https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg